# How to write multiple structures into the single file with user inputs?

Tags: c

I want to write two structures into a text file and read them later whenever I needed. I don't know how to get multiple structure inputs from the user and write them into a single file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Student_Details {
    int Num;
    char Name[15];
    char Message[100];
} Notes1;

typedef struct Additional_Details {
    float Marks;
    char Gender;
    int Class;
} Notes2;

void write(FILE *, Notes1, Notes2);
void read(FILE *);

int main()
{
    int ch;
    FILE *fp = fopen("Notes.txt", "w+");
    Notes1 txt1;
    Notes2 txt2;
    printf("Select choice\n1.Write\n2.Read\n");
    scanf("%d%*c", &ch);
    if (fp == NULL)
        printf("Could not able to open the file\n");
    else
        switch(ch) {
          case 1:
            write(fp, txt1, txt2);
          case 2:
            read(fp);
        }
   return 0;
}

void write(FILE *fp, Notes1 msg1, Notes2 msg2)
{
    printf("Enter Num,Name,Message,Marks,Gender & Class\n");
    scanf("%d%*c%s%s%f%*c%c%d",
          &msg1.Num, msg1.Name, msg1.Message,
          &msg2.Marks, msg2.Gender, &msg2.Class);
    fwrite(&msg1, sizeof(msg1), 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}

void read(FILE *fp)
{
    char ch;
    do {
        ch = fgetc(fp);
        printf("%c", ch);
    } while (ch != EOF);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

I tried `scanf()` to read inputs from user even added `%*c` after `%d` to fill up the new line character `'\n'` inserted by the `scanf()` after `%d`. It seems `fwrite()` will only take one structure as an argument and I don't know to write it into the file and I don't know to get inputs of different data types from user and store them on a file for later use. Kindly help me on this.

Comment: `char ch;` and `while(ch != EOF)` is wrong.  `EOF` is an `int` value that cannot be represented as a `char`.  Note that `fgetc()` returns an `int` and not a `char`.  `ch` must be an `int`.

Comment: You forgot about `&` for `msg2.Marks`, `msg2.Gender` and `msg2.Class` in `scanf` in `write.`

Comment: @AndrewHenle The read( ) function actually works. My main question here is how to get multiple inputs from user and store them into a single file. Kindly help me on that please

Comment: @IndyRose *The read( ) function actually works.*  **No**, it doesn't.  Put a character into your file with the value `0xFF`...  Please do not confuse "I didn't see it fail" with "It works."

Comment: @AndrewHenle: `"EOF is an int value that cannot be represented as a char"` -- This statement of yours is inaccurate. On most platforms, `EOF` has the value `-1`, which can be represented as a `char` on platforms on which a `char` is equivalent to a `signed char` (which is most platforms), but not on platforms on which a `char` is equivalent to an `unsigned char` (such platforms do exist and are permitted by the ISO C standard). The main problem is - as you have hinted - that if you use a `char` instead of `int`, the value `-1` cannot be distinguished between `EOF` and an actual character.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Using typical implementations, how can a 32-bit `int` value `0xFFFFFFFF` be represented as an 8-bit `char`?  If `EOF` *could* be represented as a `char` value it could not be used as a flag.  Your comment assumes that `int fgetc()` will return `0xFFFFFFFF` for the signed `char` value `0xFF`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel From man7 : "fgetc() reads the next character from stream and returns it as **an
       unsigned char** cast to an int, or EOF on end of file or error."

Comment: @IndyRose To me it's unclear what is the problem here. You can just call `fwrite` twice.

Comment: @SupportUkraine my write() function is not working properly

Comment: @IndyRose "not working properly" is not a good problem description. Exactly what is going wrong?'

Comment: @SupportUkraine The data is not filed properly (weird symbols are seen) even when fwrite() is called twice.

Comment: @IndyRose What is your exact input? What did you expect to happen? What did actually happen?

Comment: `EOF` is different from all `unsigned char` values returned by `fgetc()`.  It is unfortunate that `char` was a signed type on early implementations of C and this tradition remains on most platforms despite the inconsistency with the semantics of  `fgetc()` and `strcmp` who both treat byte values as `unsigned char`. It is also an endless source of undefined behavior with the functions and macros from `<ctype.h>`.

Comment: Quote: "...to fill up the new line character '\n' **inserted** by the scanf()..." Well, `scanf`will **not** insert any `\n`. If you see a `\n` then it's because the user typed one

Comment: Storing the return value of `fgetc()` into anything but an `int` is an error, because it makes `EOF` either undistinguishable from a legitimate `char` value `\377` or impossible to test on platforms where `char` is an unsigned type.

Comment: When I gave student details after selecting write() function, I can only able to see some (symbols) on the "Notes.txt" file

Comment: @IndyRose You write: "weird symbols are seen" Where do you see that?

Comment: @SupportUkraine on the Notes.txt file which is generated by fopen() function

Comment: @IndyRose Hmmmm.... So you are expecting a text file!? Maybe you should check what `fwrite` is doing...

Comment: @SupportUkraine My updated write() function, 
void write(FILE* fp,Notes1 msg1,Notes2 msg2)
{
    printf("Enter Num,Name,Message,Marks,Gender & Class\n");
    scanf("%d%*c%s%s%*c%f%*c%c%d",&msg1.Num,msg1.Name,msg1.Message,&msg2.Marks,msg2.Gender,&msg2.Class);
    fwrite(&msg1,sizeof(msg1),1,fp);
    fwrite(&msg2,sizeof(msg2),1,fp);
    fclose(fp);
}

Comment: @AndrewHenle: The value `0xFFFFFFFF` cannot be represented in a 32-bit `int`. As stated in my previous comment, most platforms define `EOF` as the value `-1` (not `0xFFFFFFFF`). This value can be converted to a `char` without any truncation, assuming that you are using a platform on which `char` is equivalent to `signed char`. The problem is that in the case of such a conversion of an 8-bit `char`, if `fgetc` returns a value in the range `128` to `255`, this value will usually be converted to the range `-128` to `-1`, so that it is no longer distinguishable from the value `EOF`.

Comment: @chqrlie: You are correct. I never stated anything to the contrary. I was only disputing the statement `"EOF is an int value that cannot be represented as a char"` which was made by another user.

Comment: @IndyRose To be more specific... `fwrite` is not what you want... Take a look at `fprintf`

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: yes, I got that and removed the comment attribution :)

Comment: @SupportUkraine Okay on that case how to get multiple inputs with various data type in scanf() function ?

Comment: @IndyRose And another advice... Forget that you ever heard about `scanf` It's very difficult to use and it has many pitfalls. Look at `fgets` instead. If you really, really need what `scanf` can do for you, use `fgets` followed by `sscanf`. It's much better.... but `sscanf` also have many pitfals so...

Comment: @IndyRose And for both `scanf` and `sscanf` you should **always** check the return value. Very important...

Comment: @IndyRose And notice `%s` only matches a single word... so a name like "Donald Duck" can't be read with a single `%s`. Further, is `Message` a single word? If not.... forget about `scanf`

Comment: @AndreasWenzel You still haven't actually answered how the 32 bits with value 0xFFFFFFFF can be accurately represented by an 8-bit `char` value.  And please do not try to muddy the waters by conflating that with the twos-complement interpretation of those bit patterns.  Because you've also ignored the fact that `fgetc()` returns the `char` as an **unsigned** value cast to `int`, which means `0xFF` char value does not get sign-extended to `0xFFFFFFFF`.

Comment: @chqrlie "It is unfortunate that char was a signed type on early implementations of C"  --> Hmmm, I am not sure that it was so much that "char was a signed type on early implementations" as much as _signed_ `char`  emerged as the early winner of the _signed_ vs. _unsigned_ battle.  I suspect _unsigned_ was the common choice for non-2's complement and common enough in 2's.  [A beginning is a very delicate time.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RZ7DkBFjLRI).

Comment: @AndreasWenzel "EOF is an int value that cannot be represented as a char" misleads. When `EOF` has a _value_ of -1 and `char` is _signed_, -1 can readily be stored, without value change, in a `char` (2's, 1s' or sign-mag makes no difference). Issue of `char`, (or `signed char`, `unsigned char`) to store the return value of `fgetc()` is better described as a [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) one.  `fgetc()` returns 256 different pos. values and 1 neg. one. Those 257 different values cannot be store distinctively in a `char`, signed or not. Info is lost.

Comment: @IndyRose There is strong agreement that `char ch;` is poor.  Use `int ch;` to distinctively store the typical 257 different return values from `fgetc()` and avoid problems.  Your code has an infinite loop when `char` is _unsigned_ as an _unsigned_ `char` would need to equal `EOF`, some negative value to exit the loop.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica *"EOF is an int value that cannot be represented as a char" misleads.*  Not if your point is to explain to an inexperienced programmer why you can't put the result of `fgetc()` into a `char` value without completely extraneous confusion.  Nevermind that it's not misleading to state that 0xFFFFFFFF can't be represented in 8 bits...

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple problems in your code and with your approach in general:

- you seem to want to write structures directly to the file as binary contents: this would require you open the file in binary mode with `"rb"` or `"wb"`, but it is error prone and not portable.  It is recommended to write the structure contents as text instead.
- you should add `break` statements after sequence of statements controlled by a `case` clause, otherwise the execution continues past the next `case`.
- `write(fp, txt1, txt2);` passes the structures by value, but these structures are uninitalized and there is no code to read them in the `main` function.  Reading the structure contents in the `write` function is inappropriate, this belong in the `read` function.
- note that `read` and `write` are standard library functions on many operating systems, so you should name your functions differently.
- the `read` function just echoes the contents of the file to standard output, which assumes textual contents, and the loop is incorrect: `ch` must be defined as an `int` for reliable `EOF` testing and you should test for `EOF` before printing the character to `stdout`. Closing the stream should be done elsewhere. Here is a modified version:

  ```
  void read(FILE *fp) {
      int ch;
      while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
          putchar(ch);
      }
  }
  ```

Here is a modified version for you to study:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Student_Details {
    int Num;
    char Name[15];
    char Message[100];
} Notes1;

typedef struct Additional_Details {
    float Marks;
    char Gender;
    int Class;
} Notes2;

int read_data(FILE *, Notes1 *, Notes2 *);
int write_data(FILE *, const Notes1 *, const Notes2 *);

int main(void) {
    Notes1 txt1 = { 0 };
    Notes2 txt2 = { 0 };
    FILE *fp;

    for (;;) {
        printf("Select choice:\n"
               "0.Input data from the user\n"
               "1.Print the structure data\n"
               "2.Read the structure data from the file\n"
               "3.Write the structure data to the file\n");
        if (scanf("%d", &ch) != 1)
            break;
        switch (ch) {
          case 0:  /* input data from the user */
            printf("Enter Num, Name, Message, Marks, Gender & Class separated by commas\n");
            read_data(stdin, &msg1, &msg2);
            break;

          case 1:  /* print the structure data */
            write_data(stdout, &msg1, &msg2);
            break;

          case 2:  /* read data from the file */
            if ((fp = fopen("Notes.txt", "r")) == NULL)
                printf("Could not open the file Notes.txt: %s\n".
                       strerror(errno));
            } else {
                read_data(fp, &msg1, &msg2);
                fclose(fp);
            }
            break;

          case 3:  /* write data to the file */
            if ((fp = fopen("Notes.txt", "w")) == NULL)
                printf("Could not open the file Notes.txt: %s\n".
                       strerror(errno));
            } else {
                write_data(fp, &msg1, &msg2);
                fclose(fp);
            }
            break;

          default:
            printf("invalid choice, exiting\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int read(FILE *fp, Notes1 *msg1, Notes2 *msg2) {
    char line[200];

    if (!fgets(line, sizeof line, fp)) {
        printf("cannot read data\n");
        return -1;
    }
    /* read data as comma separated values on a single line */
    if (sscanf(line, "%d, %14[^,], %99[^,], %f, %c, %d",
        &msg1->Num, msg1->Name, msg1->Message,
        &msg2->Marks, &msg->Gender, &msg2->Class) != 6) {
        printf("invalid format\n");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int write(FILE *fp, const Notes1 *msg1, const Notes2 *msg2) {
    /* write data as comma separated values on a single line */
    fprintf(fp, "%s, %s, %s, %f, %c, %d\n",
            msg1->Num, msg1->Name, msg1->Message,
            msg2->Marks, msg->Gender, msg2->Class);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good choice on the `sscanf()` approach.  I like the `int n = 0; sscanf(line, "%d, %14[^,], %99[^,], %f, %c, %d %n", ...., &n); if (n == 0 || line[n]) fail();` approach.  It catches junk at the end.  (Might be beyond OP at this time.)

Comment: Rather than write a `float` with `%f`, consider `%g` or `%9g`  for the usual range and distinctiveness issues.

Answer (score 1):

> As this type of problem is so commonly assigned for students I added
> an example at the end

There are many problems with the posted code, but not so many as there was in the original posted code.

Here follows some discussion about the reason of the problems and an example

> I want to get the user inputs of different structure members and store them into a single text file. Which function should I use to get integer inputs and string inputs from user and which function should I use to store the structure data to the file

- `scanf` is not a good choice when reading data from `stdin`. `scanf` and family were written to consume tabular data, things like *csv* files, and is very good at that. Files that have thousands of lines of the same info, lines then called then records, with values called fields, separated by some delimiter like a comma, as in comma separated values, *csv* files.

  - `scanf` skips blank space, things like spaces and tabs until it gets the required data, or no more data
  - `scanf` can read nothing and it is not an error.
  - `scanf` returns an `int` that must be checked always. The return value is the number of items in the specifier that could be read. Since you did not test and the user can type anything, your program can and will easily fail.

  #### The specifiers for `scanf`

  ```
          "%d%*c%s%s%f%d"
  ```

  This is the mask used here and it makes no sense. It is wrong. Here the error makes no harm because the next field after `%*c` is a string and the previous is a number, so the space would be skipped anyway.

  - `%*c` means that a field of a single char must be skipped and will not count in the return value, the one you did not tested anyway
  - this is the same as

```
            "%d%s%s%f%d"
```

- since you have 5 specifiers `scanf` can return `0` to `5` depending on what could be read. Or `-1` in case of error. I hope now you see why you need to test for it.

#### Example

If the user enter this 5 lines:

```
12 name

message
1.
2
```

every specifier is satisfied and `scanf` returns 5. The fields in the structs will all get the expected values

But if the user enter this line:

```
name message 12.12 42
```

`scanf` returns `0` and all your fields remain unchanged. Since `scanf` could not get the `RollNo` field it returns immediately. And your program fails.

#### `scanf` will not read 2 strings with spaces

if the user enters

```
12 my name my message 12.12 42
```

`scanf` will return `3`, `RollNo` will be 12 `Name` will be "my", `Message` will be "name", `Marks` and `Class` will remain unchanged.

Maybe you would expect to have `Name` as "my name" and `Message` as "my message" for the strings, but this is not how it works.`scanf`, `fscanf` and `sscanf` have another purpose.

#### So what to use?

I hope that now you know a bit more about `scanf` use. Use `fgets` and read full lines. Then parse the line (or lines) and get your data. You can always use `atoi`, `atod` or `atof` to convert data to the desired format. Manage user input is yes boring.

#### so `scanf` is useless?

As I said, these functions were intended to consume tabular data, like csv files, since the 70's. In fact is a good way even today to consume data, as csv are very efficient as output for BI large data tables.

#### Example

A bit off-topic but if your data could use comma separated values you could use this mask:

```
         "%d,%[^,],%[^,],%f,%d"
```

meaning:

- read an int until a comma
- skip the comma
- read everything until another comma as a string

  - `[^,]` macthes all data until a comma, and it includes spaces and tabs, so `msg1.Name` can be "my name" as above
- read everything until another comma as a string
- read a `float` until the next comma
- read an `int` until the next comma

  So this `scanf` call

  ```
  const char* mask = "%d,%[^,],%[^,],%f,%d";
  int res = scanf( mask, 
      &msg1.RollNo, msg1.Name, msg1.Message,
      &msg2.Marks, &msg2.Class
  );
  ```

will get `res = 5` for this data:

```
12,my name,my message,12.,42
```

And you will get the expected values, like "my message" for `msg1.Message`

I left the specifier in a separate line just for readability.

As noted by **David** in the comments, when using `scanf` we should always put a limit on the size of the fields, so the safe `mask` should be

```
        const char* mask = "%d,%14[^,],%99[^,],%f,%d";
```

#### why they teach using `scanf` for getting (non tabular) user input?

May be for laziness of teaching about conversion functions like `atoi` before writing simple programs to read  single values. I do not know. In K&R book `scanf` only appears after around 120 pages, and this is half the total pages in the book.

#### about the code

```
typedef struct Student_Details
{
    int  RollNo;
    char Name[15];
    char Message[100];
} Notes1;

typedef struct Additional_Details
{
    float Marks;
    int   Class;
} Notes2;
```

this structs should be anonymous. There is no use for the names.

May be this is part of a more complex task, but here these structs are a single one. There is always  `Notes1` and `Notes2`.

Could be

```
typedef struct 
{
    int  RollNo;
    char Name[15];
    char Message[100];
} Notes1;

typedef struct 
{
    float Marks;
    int   Class;
} Notes2;
```

or even

```
typedef struct 
{
    int  RollNo;
    char Name[15];
    char Message[100];

    float Marks;
    int   Class;
} Student;
```

Also note that in the code you did no test if there was a previous read operation if the user selects to write data, and the structs are not initialized or valid...

#### `fwrite` vs `fprintf`

In general if you write text as in a report you use `fprintf` to write formatted text, files composed of lines of possibly variable length. If you write bytes to files in general you open them in binary mode and write records of some sort

### An Example using `fgets()`

As this is a so common task for students I will left below a very very primitive example, with output

#### output from the example

```
Enter values for student

    Roll#: 1
    Name: Mary Jane
    Message: A note from Mary
    Marks: 12.34
    Class: 2023

    [Value input by user]

  Student:
    Roll: 1
    Name: "Mary Jane"
    Message: "A note from Mary"
    Marks:  12.34, Class: 2023


    [Student from const literal]

  Student:
    Roll: 42
    Name: "John Henry Brown"
    Message: "message from John"
    Marks:  42.42, Class: 42
```

#### `Notes.txt` from the example

```
1,"Mary Jane","A note from Mary", 12.34,2023
42,"John Henry Brown","message from John", 42.42,42
```

#### `C` code for the example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int   roll_no;
    char  name[20];
    char  message[30];
    float marks;
    int   class_no;
} Student;

int read_st(FILE*, Student*);
int show_st(Student*,const char*);
int write_st(FILE*, Student*);

int main(void)
{
    FILE* fp = fopen("Notes.txt", "w");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(
            stderr, "Could not able to open the file\n");
        return -1;
    }
    Student st = {0};

    read_st(fp,&st);
    show_st(&st, "Value input by user");
    write_st(fp, &st);

    // using a literal for testing
    Student other = {
        .roll_no  = 42,
        .name     = "John Henry Brown",
        .message  = "message from John",
        .marks    = 42.42f,
        .class_no = 42};
    show_st(&other, "Student from const literal");
    write_st(fp, &other);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

int  read_st(FILE* fp, Student* st)
{
    char line[80] = {0};
    char* p        = NULL;
    if (fp == NULL) return -2;
    if (st == NULL) return -3;
    // Roll
    printf("Enter values for student\n\n    Roll#: ");
    p    = fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
    if (p == NULL) return -1;
    st->roll_no = atoi(line);
    // name
    printf("    Name: ");
    p           = fgets(st->name, sizeof(st->name), stdin);
    // read the manual
    // value can have a '\n' at the end
    int pos = strlen(st->name) - 1;
    if (st->name[pos] == '\n') st->name[pos] = 0; // deleted
    if (p == NULL) return -1;
    // message
    printf("    Message: ");
    p = fgets(st->message, sizeof(st->message), stdin);
    if (p == NULL) return -1;
    // value can have a '\n' at the end
    pos = strlen(st->message) - 1;
    if (st->message[pos] == '\n')
        st->message[pos] = 0;  // deleted
    // marks
    printf("    Marks: ");
    p         = fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
    st->marks   = (float) atof(line);
    if (p == NULL) return -1;
    // class
    printf("    Class: ");
    p = fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
    if (p == NULL) return -1;
    st->class_no = atoi(line);
    return 0;
}

int write_st(FILE* fp, Student* st)
{
    if (fp == NULL) return -1;
    if (st == NULL) return -2;
    fprintf(
        fp, "%d,\"%s\",\"%s\",%6.2f,%d\n", st->roll_no,
        st->name, st->message, st->marks, st->class_no);
    return 0;
}

int show_st(Student* st, const char* msg)
{
    if (st == NULL) return -1;
    if (msg != NULL) printf("\n    [%s]\n", msg);
    printf(
        "\n\
  Student:\n\
    Roll: %d\n\
    Name: \"%s\"\n\
    Message: \"%s\"\n\
    Marks: %6.2f, Class: %d\n\n",
        st->roll_no, st->name, st->message, st->marks,
        st->class_no);
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: Very good effort on the answer and formatting. A couple of additional comments may help as well. When reading anything into character arrays with `scanf()` the *field-width* must be specified to protect the array bound. E.g. in `%[^,],%[^,]` each string specifier would need the *field-width* of `size - 1` to preserve room for the nul-terminating character and prevent writing beyond the array end. The verbiage for `"%*c` is the `'*'` is the *assignment suppression* operator -- which does exactly what you said (read and discard the matching character without affecting the *match-count*)

Comment: Hi @IndyRose. I added an example of code using `fgets` with comments and output. I hope you find my explanation also useful!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks for pointing this. I added a note in the answer

Comment: If I could vote twice I would, but I've given all I can `:)` The beauty of `fgets()` is it will read an entire line of input, including the `'\n'` into a sufficiently sized buffer. You can trim the `'\n'` with `buffer[strcspn (buffer, "\n")] = 0;` or simply pass `buffer` to `sscanf(buffer, ..., ...)`; There, the benefit is the read and parse are decoupled allowing validation of the input and the parse separately. `scanf()` is full of pitfalls for the new C programmer. Using `fgets()` for all user input is more robust -- and it eliminates all the `scanf()` pitfalls. Can't go wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Easy and Classic.

Use `fread` / `fwrite`. In the Arguments it's a pointer. If you want to write a single value, it have to be in a pointer, and then read the 1st element of the pointer.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    float ** array;  //[y][x] -> float
    int X, Y;
} A_t;

A_t * mk_A(int X, int Y) {
    A_t * a = malloc(sizeof(A_t));
    a->X = X;
    a->Y = Y;
    a->array = malloc(sizeof(float*) * Y);
    for (int i=0; i < Y; i++) a->array[i] = calloc(X, sizeof(float));
    //
    return a;
};

void free_A(A_t * a) {
    for (int i=0; i < a->Y; i++) free(a->array[i]);
    free(a->array);
    free(a);
};


// Directly write every bits of your array and data you are pointing to
void write_A(A_t * a, char * file) {
    FILE * fp = fopen(file, "wb"); // wb = write binary.
    
    // Write single values
    fwrite(&a->X, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    fwrite(&a->X, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    
    // Write arrays and pointers to other data fiels
    for (int y=0; y < a->Y; y++)
         fwrite(a->array[y], sizeof(float), a->X, fp);  //write the array[y] floats byte by byte

    //
    fclose(fp);
};

A_t* read_A(char * file) {
     A_t * ret = malloc(sizeof(A_t));
     //
     FILE * fp = fopen(file, "rb");  //read bin
     //
     fread(&ret->X, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
     fread(&ret->Y, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
     //
     ret->array = malloc(sizeof(float*) * ret->Y);
     for (int i=0; i < ret->Y; i++) {
          ret->array[i] = malloc(sizeof(float) * ret->X);
          fread(ret->array[i], sizeof(float) * ret->X, fp);
     }
     //
     fclose(fp);
     return ret;
};

//======================================================

int main() {
    A_t * a = mk_A(10, 38);
    // ... do stuff with a ...
    write_A(a, "file");
    free_A(a);
    //
    a = read_A("file");
    // you will see it's the same 
};
```